# How to check for an empty object in an AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the controller's scope I have something like:

```
$scope.card = {};
```

In the view I must check if my object is still an empty literal, `{}`, or if it contains some data in some fields.

I tried this:

```
ng-show="angular.equals({}, card)"
```

and

```
ng-show="!angular.equals({}, card)"
```

but it didn't work.

Are there any better ways? How do you check if an object is empty or if it contains some fields?

Comment: try this: `JSON.stringify(a) == "{}"`

Comment: :) `JSON.stringify($scope.card).length <= 2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: Checking if a js object is empty,works with ng-show but not from controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839141/angularjs-checking-if-a-js-object-is-empty-works-with-ng-show-but-not-from-cont)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use: `Object.keys(card).length === 0`

But make sure you use it from a method of the controller as the `Object` is not available in the view, like:

```
$scope.isObjectEmpty = function(card){
   return Object.keys(card).length === 0;
}
```

Then you can call the function from the view:

```
ng-show="!isObjectEmpty(card)"
```

Comment: i know that, but i need it from the view!

Comment: @brabertaser1992, Create a function, pass object as paramter and return true false

Comment: @brabertaser1992, what you wanted to do is not possible AFAIK. Because, the card object needs to have a property function which can do the job. But it's not available. you need to do it through the $scope.

Answer (score 20):

Use `json` filter and compare with `'{}'` string.

```
<div>
    My object is {{ (myObject | json) == '{}' ? 'Empty' : 'Not Empty' }}
</div>
```

`ng-show`   example:

```
<div ng-show="(myObject | json) != '{}'"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
angular.equals({}, $scope.card)
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a function that checks whether the object is empty:

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Then, you can check like so in your html:

```
ng-show="!isEmpty(card)"
```

Answer (score 6):

http://plnkr.co/edit/u3xZFRKYCUh4D6hGzERw?p=preview

Because angular is not available from the scope, you can pass it to your controller scope.

```
$scope.angular = angular;
```

Comment: Actually I though you were wrong but you just saved my day on this.

Answer (score 5):

please try this way with filter

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('isEmpty', function () {
        var bar;
        return function (obj) {
            for (bar in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(bar)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
    });
```

usage:

```
 <p ng-hide="items | isEmpty">Some Content</p>
```

Via from : [Checking if object is empty, works with ng-show but not from controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839141/angularjs-checking-if-a-js-object-is-empty-works-with-ng-show-but-not-from-cont)

Comment: Good snippet. Saved for my projects.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the object empty checking:

```
<div ng-if="isEmpty(card)">Object Empty!</div>


$scope.isEmpty = function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not initialize your variable to an empty object, but let it be `undefined` or `null` until the conditions exist where it should have a non-`null`/`undefined` value:

```
$scope.card;

if (someCondition = true) {
    $scope.card = {};
}
```

Then your template:

```
ng-show="card"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, this is an advice. Should be in the comment of his question, not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain javascript Object class to achieve it,
Object class has keys function which takes 1 argument as input as follows,

> Object.keys(obj).length === 0

You can achieve it in 3 ways,
1) Current controller scope
2) Filter
3) $rootScope

1) First way is current controller scope,

> $scope.isObjEmpty = function(obj){
>         return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;   }

Then you can call the function from the view:

ng-show="!isObjEmpty(obj)" if you want to show and hide dom dynamically & 
ng-if="!isObjEmpty(obj)" if you want to remove or add dom dynamically.

2) The second way is a custom filter. Following code should work for the object & Array,

```
angular.module('angularApp')
    .filter('isEmpty', [function () {
        return function (obj) {
            if (obj == undefined || obj == null || obj == '')
                return true;
            if (angular.isObject(obj))
                return Object.keys(obj).length != 0;

            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
    }]);

    <div ng-hide="items | isEmpty"> Your content's goes here </div>
```

3) The third way is $rootScope, 
create a plain javascript function and add it in $rootScope server it will accessible default in all scopes and UI.

> function isObjEmpty (obj){
>         return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;   }
>
> $rootScope.isObjEmpty  = isObjEmpty ;

Answer (score 0):

Create a `$scope` function that check it and returns true or false, like a "isEmpty" function and use in your view on `ng-if` statement  like

```
ng-if="isEmpty(object)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met a similar problem when checking emptiness in a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). In this case, the controller must define a method that actually performs the test and the view uses it:

```
function FormNumericFieldController(/*$scope, $element, $attrs*/ ) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.isEmptyObject = function(object) {
        return angular.equals(object, {});
    }
}

<!-- any validation error will trigger an error highlight -->
<span ng-class="{'has-error': !$ctrl.isEmptyObject($ctrl.formFieldErrorRef) }">
    <!-- validated control here -->
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to validate an empty object check as below

ex:

```
<div  data-ng-include="'/xx/xx/xx/regtabs.html'" data-ng-if =
    "$parent.$eval((errors | json) != '{}')" >
</div>
```

The error is my scope object, it is being defined in my controller as `$scope.error = {};`

Comment: Hi Priya! Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you edit your answer & explain why your code is cool, then it stands a better chance of receiving upvotes. Those will boost your reputation upwards! Here are some suggestions, which will help to make your answer better: 1. When creating answers, would you please add the proper capitalization & punctuation to your answers? 2. Could you edit the code example, to remove the extra white-spacing between attributes? 3. Adding links to external documentation or quotes from those sources are usually helpful too. Welcome to the SO community! :)

Answer (score 0):

A good and effective way is to use a **"json pipe"** like the following in your HTML file:

```
   <pre>{{ yourObject | json }}</pre>
```

which allows you to see clearly if the object is empty or not.

I tried quite a few ways that are showed here, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using a lot of the methods and properties of Object in your Angular JS app, why not use:

```
angular.module('core').run(function ($rootScope) {
     $rootScope.Object = window.Object;
});
```

Then in your view, you could do something like:

```
<div ng-if="Object.keys(fooBar).length > 0"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to just check that the object is null or not. AngularJs provide inbuilt directive `ng-if`. An example is given below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="key in object" ng-if="object != 'null'" >
    <td>{{object.key}}</td>
    <td>{{object.key}}</td>
</tr>
```